# Why is the value is not updated between multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

The following program does a basic multi threading task.I have two threads in one class. One thread does the work of increasing a value variable and another that checks the value and displays a message.

```
Class Was{
private int ctime;
private int value;
public Thread w,c;

public was(int a) {
    ctime=a;
    w = new Thread(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() { 
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(ctime*1000);
                    value++; 
                }
                System.out.printf("\nIncreasing done");
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    } 
    });

    c = new Thread(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() { 
            try {
                for(;;) {
                    if(value==3) {
                        w.wait();
                        System.out.printf("\nValue reached");
                        w.notify();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

`main class`

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String z[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temp;
        System.out.printf("\nEnter the sleeping time in seconds: ");
        temp=s.nextInt();
        was m = new was(temp);
        m.w.start();
        m.c.start();
    }
}
```

The c thread never tells that the value has been reached. I do not understand why.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions, classes start with uppercase. Please format your code.

Comment: this [example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr1) may help.

Answer (score 8):

> The c thread never tells that the value has been reached. I do not understand why.

When you share values between threads, you need to use some mechanism to synchronize the memory that holds the value.  This can be done with a `synchronize` block, marking the value as `volatile`, or using (in this case) an `AtomicInteger`.  Here's a [good tutorial on the memory consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

The `AtomicInteger` is the right thing to use here because it allows the thread to increment safely.  You have to remember that increment is *not* an atomic operation because it is really get, increment, and set.

Your code would look something like:

```
private final AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
...
value.incrementAndGet();
...
if (value.get() == 3) ...
```

Also, as @Boris pointed out you have the following code:

```
w.wait();
System.out.printf("\nValue reached");
w.notify();
```

This won't compile because you are not in a `synchronized` block.  Also, having a `wait()` and then a `notify()` is a little of of a strange pattern.   You might also want to read the [tutorial on guarded blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Comment: There is also a usage of `wait` and `notify` outside of a `synchronized` blocked on a `Thread` object - I'm not sure the `int` is the only issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason that over the last 3 minutes, you have edited the answer 5 or 6 times, adding more content to the answer all the time? I may be "the new kids" between the two of us, but is it really common to just "get the answer out" as soon as possible, and then add all the *vital* points to the answer afterwards?

Comment: To provide a little background on this for the OP: pretty much all of today's CPUs have multiple cores, and each core has its own cache to speed up access to recently used variables. Because of this, changing a variable from one thread doesn't necessarily mean a different thread will see it; the new value may be living exclusively in the mutating thread's cache, and the other thread may be running on a different core. However, making everything synchronized by default would be a huge performance hit and would also slow down single-threaded programs, so you have to specify it yourself.

Comment: Yeah @Izmaki, that's the way I typically answer questions.  If I would take the time to write and edit all of this then I'd never get a point on SO.  I answered the key point which mentions memory synchronization and use of `AtomicInteger` and then I go back and fill it in with links to docs and sample code and the like.

Comment: @Gray I must say I find it slightly cheesy, but I guess that's how it works here (and why I'm only at the 300-mark).

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out. I am actually developing a multithreaded application. In that i need to make another thread wait on a certain condition and execute a task and then notify the thread. But i am unable to call wait method of another thread from a thread. Kindly help me on the issue.

Comment: I think you need to post another question @Ragz.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to code, same requirement but different design. So what I understood is that thread W and C should share same monitor through which one gets notified when other signals  to do so . So in this case Object lock act as an monitor. I passed same instance of Object (lock) to both thread and calls wait and notify on that lock. And it works fine. 
    package com.stackoverflow.gin;

```
public class Main {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    private C c = new C(lock);
    private W w = new W(lock);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main u = new Main();
        u.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Start");
        c.start();
        w.start();
    }

    public class W extends Thread {
        private Object lock;

        public W(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Notify C that I have finished work");
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "W");
            }
        }
    }

    public class C extends Thread {
        private int times = 0;
        private Object lock;

        public C(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for W to finish ");
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.println("W has notified " + times);
                    times++;
                    if (times == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Every thing is done, lets die to gether");
                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually wanted to make the thread c to check if the value has reached 3. If so make the thread w wait temporarily and print a message and then resume the thread w to complete its task of updating the value to 5.
After making the variable value atomic i could achieve synchronization in Value. But i get illegalmonitorstate exception when i use w.wait(). I need to do a task by making the w thread actually. It would be nice if you could help me achieve it in your new design or my design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can or should put one thread to wait from other thread. Its like two bus running parallel and one bus want to put break in other. That does not make sense. Or its not a good design. I don't know following is what you are looking for but  have a look and let me know .

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    private C c = new C(lock);
    private W w = new W(lock);
    private AtomicInteger times = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main u = new Main();
        u.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Start");
        c.start();
        w.start();
    }

    public class W extends Thread {
        private Object lock;

        public W(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    times.set(i + 1);
                    System.out.println("Incremented counter " + times.get());
                }
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("Notify C that I have finished work");
                    lock.notify();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "W");
            }
        }
    }

    public class C extends Thread {
        private Object lock;

        public C(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    if (times.get() == 3) {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            System.out.println("Now I will wait until W finishes with his work");
                            lock.wait();
                            System.out.println("Ok W is finished with the loop " + times.get() + " lets exit the sytem.");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks... your design worked for me! Thanks a lot for helping out.